# Making both the background image clickable as well as the contents clickable

Tags: html, css

I would like to make both the background image as well as the contents in it clickable. I am not sure how to implement it...

The image:

[image]

I want both image as well as the contents to be clickable.

The html portion:

```
<div class = "reportslistitem">
   <a href="[[ url ]]"
       target=="_blank">
          [[ startdate ]] -
           [[ enddate ]]
   </a>  
</div>
```

The css portion:

```
.reportslistitem{
    width:120px;
    height:140px;
    display:block;
    float: right;
    background:url('../images/Report-icon-without-text.png');
}


a{
 font: bold 12px 'Thin2Regular';
 text-decoration: none;
 color: rgb(0,0,0);
 padding: 10px 15px;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 display:block;
 padding: 0px;
 position:relative;
 top:25px;
 }
```

How do i change it? Need some guidance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use HTML5 it is now valid to wrap whole sections with anchor tags so it would be

```
<a href="[[ url ]]" target="_blank">
   <div class = "reportslistitem">
          [[ startdate ]] - [[ enddate ]]
   </div> 
</a>
```

CSS should be something like

```
.reportslistitem{
    width:120px;
    height:140px;
    display:block;
    background:url('../images/Report-icon-without-text.png');
}


a{
 font: bold 12px 'Thin2Regular';
 text-decoration: none;
 color: rgb(0,0,0);
 padding: 10px 15px;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0px;
 display:block;
 width:120px;
 height:140px;
 }​
```

Comment: you need to tweek your css, if you can add your code to this http://jsfiddle.net/ I'd be more than happy to get it to work

Comment: OK let me try and figure it out

Comment: i must use position: relative and shift it back right? but why does it move down?

Comment: Can you confirm if this is working? If so please mark as a correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A background can't be clickable. Though you can emulate such a behavior by assigning the background image to a link.

Just remove/leave out the `DIV` and set this class to the anchor. `display: block;` may also be assigned to the link to allow the specification of a width and height.